# Automatically? join std::thread when task is finished

Tags: c++, stdthread

i Have an application that creates a std::thread to run a long loop.
It gets a std::future so it can be aborted.

The thread looks something like this:

```
void MyThreadObject::myThread(std::future<void> *abort)
{      
    for(size_t i=0; i<100000; i++)
    { 
        doStuff();

        // for aborting
        if(abort->wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1)) != std::future_status::timeout)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

The abort looks like this:

```
void MyThreadObject::stopThread()
{
    m_abort_signal.set_value();   //  type std::promise<void>

    //Wait for thread to join
    m_thread->join();             // type is std::thread

    delete m_thread;
    m_thread = nullptr;

    doOtherStuffWhenThreadIsFinished(); 
}
```

Now when i start and stop the thread everything works fine.

But there is also the cast (which is most cases) that the thread has finished because the loop reached its end value and the user did not abort it. 
In that case stopThread() never gets called.

My problem is that in that case I somewhere need to call join(), as well as doOtherStuffWhenThreadIsFinished(); 
But from where?

Comment: You are basically asking for a thread that detaches or joins itself. This is usually more trouble than it is worth. Consider implementing a `join` equivalent for your worker that the caller has to call, whether or not it was aborted.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: As far as I understand the thread cannot join itself because it would lead to a deadlock. 
What I have at the moment is following: There are two buttons in the GUI, first calls startThread() second calls StopThread(). That is working. What I'm searching for is how to avoid that StopThread() has to be pressed, when the loop in the thread has already stoped because the computation is finished.

Comment: @goaran Yes, you are asking how to have a thread cause itself to be joined, this is a thread joining itself, this generally doesn't work. You need to have another thread be in charge of your worker. You can use a messaging approach like Qt's signal/slot system. You can have a timer-like thread polling the state of the worker. You can ask the user to always hit "stop". But you shouldn't expect the worker thread to do any of this in a self-contained way.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Thanks for the quick reply. Yes you are right, I guess what I am searching for is something similar to QThread::finished() signal, how could i implement something like that in bare c++?.
I also have thought about having a second thread with a timed polling as you suggested, but this just moves the same problem to that thread?

Comment: Qt's signaling uses a message queue operated by a top level thread that runs through it until the application ends. Having a polling thread does not move the problem for the same reason Qt's signal system works. You can join that thread more easily, for example with the main thread (the one that calls `main`) when the application ends. In the most basic sense, you can create your top level thread at the start of `main` and `abort` + `join` it at the end of `main`. If you don't need the main thread for anything else, it can even be the main thread that does the polling.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Ok, thanks for the nice explanation. That seems like an option, I'll give it a try.